# Definition for relation to be in 3NF using canonical cover

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf, candidate-key

We are using following definition of 3NF:

> A schema R is in third normal form (3NF) if for all FD α → β in F
> +, at least one of the following holds:
>
> 1. α → β is trivial (i.e., β ⊆ α).
> 2. α is a superkey for R
> 3. Each attribute A in β – α is contained in a candidate key for R
>    (prime).

I don't understand the third condition for this definition. OK, each atribute A in β
–β
–
α means? What set of attributes does it include?
α is contained in candidate key of R. What set of attributes does it include?

Comment: It means a(alpha) is a prime attribute, since any part of a candidate key means its a prime attribute.

Comment: This is unclear/strange. Why "β –β – α", it seems a typo for "β – α". What do you mean, "α is contained in candidate key of R"? α → β is a FD in F+. A is an attribute that may be in a CK. How are you parsing (3)? Where are you 1st stuck? Where are you 1st unable to identify a symbol or expression? Otherwise you're expecting us to do that for you with no idea what you misunderstand or don't or do understand. PS When giving a definition use iff/when, not if. Using if relies on the reader to use the fact that it's a definition to properly misinterpret the if as an iff/when. PS Other typos too.

Answer (score -1):

β – α is the set of the attributes β minus the attributes that are in α, if any. So the third rule says that we can have attributes determinated by something which is not a superkey, but *only* if those attributes are primes (i.e. part of a candidate key), and obviously are not already in the determinant α (otherwise we have a trivial dependency).

So, when a relation schema *is not* in third normal form? When all the three conditions are false: that is when we have at least a non-trivial dependency whose determinant is not a superkey (so neither a candidate key) and whose right part contains attributes that are not prime.